# UI tests for application with data model changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

(I'm not sure whether this question should be in StackOverflow or maybe in a different [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) site).

I want to create **UI tests** to an **ASP.NET MVC 5** Web application. The problem is that in every new release the application adds lots of new functionality that involves new tables, new business data entries and all that stuff, so lots of **[DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)** changes. In addition to that, every release introduces new views, functions, stored procedures and [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) changes.

I'd like to **keep the code base independent of the database**, so I don't need to create a proper database for that code base version, in order to keep things as simple as possible and use automation.

My first idea was: since we use **EF**, let the DbContext initialization create the schema from the model when creating the context:

```
public MyContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>()));
}
```

and every test creates its test data at the beginning and cleans up everything at the end.

So far, so good, but I have a problem: what happens with the **stored procedures**? The application uses lots of them and I don't know how could I avoid depending on them. How could I workaround them to test the application without the need of setting up a database physically so that tests use it?

Comment: You're using code first to manage your schema right? Why not also use code first to manage your stored procedures?

Comment: We're calling stored procedures by using SqlQuery; could you please ellaborate a little bit your suggestion, please? I've surfed the web and apparently this is the way to do it, but I cannot figure out how EntityFramework could generate the stored procedures for me, or how could I mock results as a workaround.

Comment: You could use the Sql("...") methods on the migrations to run your stored procedure creation, it's a bit of a manual process, but you can then have everything about your DB be in the migrations, so you can add an Up and Down to add/remove the sproc and it'll be managed for you. Just make sure you put all changes to them through a migration.